# ZXing QrCode renderer exception with .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, qr-code, zxing, zxing.net

I would like to create a QR code with using ZXing(0.16.4) But I meet following exception,

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'You have to set a renderer
>   instance.'

Almost the same code works well with .Net Framework 4.6.1

here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var qrCode = CreateQrCode("test");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static byte[] CreateQrCode(string content)
{
    BarcodeWriter<Bitmap> writer = new BarcodeWriter<Bitmap>
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
        }
    };

    var qrCodeImage = writer.Write(content); // BOOM!!

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        qrCodeImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue, Basically I used https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.CoreCompat.System.Drawing

I create BarcodeWriter generated from following namespace

> ZXing.CoreCompat.System.Drawing

here is my CreateQrCode method

```
public static byte[] CreateQrCode(string content)
{
    BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
        }
    };

    var qrCodeImage = writer.Write(content); // BOOM!!

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        qrCodeImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Here is the read QR code method, maybe someone will need as well.
BarcodeReader also generated from the same namespace like create.

Here is the method

```
public static string ReadQrCode(byte[] qrCode)
{
    BarcodeReader coreCompatReader = new BarcodeReader();

    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(qrCode))
    {
        using (var coreCompatImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            return coreCompatReader.Decode(coreCompatImage).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this answer will protect someone's hair against pulling.

Answer (score 3):

There is a newer version of the package available and it works with .NET Core 3.1.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility/

Comment: Works perfectly with .NET Core

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently moving to .net 6 and I used `BarcodeWriter` from `ZXing.Net.Bindings.SkiaSharp` NuGet package.

```
using ZXing.SkiaSharp;
```

```
var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
{
     Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
     Options = new EncodingOptions
     {
         Height = _height,
         Width = _width,
         Margin = _margin
     }
};
using var bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(qrValue);
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Encode(stream, SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
```

Your stream is filled now :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add "Renderer = new ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer()" when using ZXing.Net v0.16.6

```
public static byte[] CreateQrCode(string content)
{
    byte[] imageData;

    var qrWriter = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter<System.Drawing.Bitmap>
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions { Height = 100, Width = 100, Margin = 0 },
        Renderer = new ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer()
    };

    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap pixelData = qrWriter.Write(content))
    {
        pixelData.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        imageData = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return imageData;
}
```